# how can a generic be <Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>

Tags: java

I've receive a question:

*Write an implementation of the TreeMap class by storing a data member of type
TreeSet `<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>`.*

I tough I should make a  treemap class like a Treeset + implementing Map interface, what do they mean *"storing a data member of type `TreeSet<<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>`"*

and how can the generic be `<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) implements `NavigableMap`, not just `Map`.

Comment: @Andreas I originally just posted `TreeSet<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();`, and then I felt like that needed a little more... like where `KeyType` and `ValueType` came from.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My comment was about your ***maybe***, that says `implements Map`, which should be `implements NavigableMap`.

Answer (score 3):

> Write an implementation of the `TreeMap` class by storing a data member of type `TreeSet <Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>`

By *"Write an implementation of the TreeMap class"*, I interpret that as meaning to implement your own class with behavior similar to the built-in [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) class, i.e. an implementation of the [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface.

By "*by storing a data member of type X*", I interpret that as meaning for your class with have a field of type X.

So, you need to implement this class:

```
public class MyTreeMap<KeyType, ValueType> implements NavigableMap<KeyType, ValueType> {
    private TreeSet<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> data;

    // your code here
}
```

For your convenience, here are some of the (easy) methods:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> entrySet() {
    return this.data;
}
public void clear() {
    this.data.clear();
}
public int size() {
    return this.data.size();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

My interpretation is for the `TreeSet` to use a `Comparator` that compares the `Entry` by the key, so that you can do the following (pseudo-code):

```
public ValueType get(Object key) {
    Entry<...> dummy = new DummyEntry<...>(key);
    Entry<...> found = this.data.ceiling(dummy);
    if (found != null && comparator.compare(found, dummy) == 0)
        return found.getValue();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your `data` defaults to `null`. Should probably *initialize* it somewhere (otherwise, great answer).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch True, but I didn't show any constructors, which would likely initialize the field there, since the `TreeSet` may need constructor parameter values to be initialized correctly, assuming you want to implement the same [4 constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#constructor.summary) that the built-in `TreeMap` has.